# Can I run powershell commands without installing module?

Tags: powershell

I would like to run a script that requires to use commands from the GroupPolicy module. However, this module is not guaranteed to be installed on every machine and some machines might be stand alone.  Can I have have the module copied over with my scripts and run commands from it, without installing the module?

Comment: Are you able to establish a PS Session with the remote computers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I have have the module copied over with my scripts and run commands from it, without installing the module?

Yes. Installing a module in PowerShell simply means placing it one of the directories listed in the `$env:PSModulePath` environment variable, which allows PowerShell to discover it and import (load) it on demand, as part of the [module auto-loading feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading)

However, you're free to copy modules elsewhere, as long as the code that relies on them knows their path and loads them with an explicit [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) call.

For instance, if you bundle your script with a `GroupPolicy` subdirectory containing that module, the script could import it as follows:

```
# $PSScriptRoot contains the calling script's directory.
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\GroupPolicy
```